# Rspec Testing of real time results through mTurk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mechanicalturk

I am creating hits at mTurk through Rspec test code but at the same time i need to test the results which must be send back from mTurk. In order to save complexity testing for every test i'm using VCR to record the HTTP Requests in a cassette. How can i implement this test??

Comment: I think your title is a bit misleading for what you are trying to achieve. You are probably aware that VCR will give you the opposite of real time results, it stores the response so it gives you a canned response that it made the request for once. Are you asking just how you use VCR to test mTurk, or how to write a test for mTurk?

Comment: @bobby, well i did some hack for that :), i used debugger to hold my rspec test until results comes back from mTurk and then it get stored in VCR. so i have to do this kinda hack once and then after that VCR works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i did some hack for that, i used debugger to hold my rspec test until results comes back from mTurk and then it get stored in VCR. so i have to do this kinda hack once and then after that VCR works for me